# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2 - x^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, tangent-line

I've just started with differential equations and in the textbook I was given two, with one of which I have trouble. The task was to solve them with software, but I considered it'd be better to solve by hand. But since it's just the start of the topic in the textbook, not much has been provided about how to do it.

The equation and the initial value problem are:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2 - x^2}} \\\
y(0) = 2
$$

I looked into two tables of integrals (so it's doublechecked) and found this:

$$
\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{a}}} + C
$$

But the problem is that y is not defined at 0 (if the tables are correct). Since y(0) = 2 might be a typo in the textbook, I tried to check whether the solution would work for some other point. I took x = 1 and C = 0 and tried to plot y and t (the tangent) in software:

$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{x}{a}}} \\\
y'(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\\
t(x) = \frac{x - x_0}{\sqrt{3}} + t(x_0) = \frac{x - 1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$
[image]

As you can see, t (the yellow curve) is definitely not tangent to y(x). But it seems normal, and indeed, when I changed the yellow to $t(x) = -\sqrt{3}(x - 1) + \frac{1}{\sin{\frac{1}{2}}}$ it became tangent at x = 1.

So could anyone, please, explain, what's going on here? Did I use the integral tables correctly? **How come the function under the integral sign (which is a derivative) gives not a tangent but normal to the right hand side of the integral solution?**

Thank you.

Comment: @Aryadeva yes, this was from the integral tables I used

Comment: You're confusing $\dfrac1{\sin\frac xa}$ and $\arcsin\frac xa$, also denoted (in a disastrous way) $\sin^{-1}\frac xa$.

Comment: Many books use that notation @Bernard

Comment: @Bernard: the disaster here is the ancient convention that $\sin^n\,x$ means $(\sin\, x)^n$.

Comment: You wrote:  "The task was to solve them with software, but I considered it'd be better to solve by hand."  Watch this and re-consider:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: @RobArthan :The notation $\sin^{-1}$ for the arcsine was borrowed, in my opinion to the handheld computers manufactures which couldn't make the six letters of $\arcsin$ on a single key. For a similar reason, I wonder why almost everyone uses `\mathbb`  to type the various number sets, a font which is supposed to reproduce  boldface written with a piece of chalk!

Comment: @Aryadeva: Well, I think they shouldn't. As you can see,it is quite ambiguous. Furthermore, it is quite recent and  borrowed from computer scientists.

Comment: @Bernard: using $f^{-1}$ to denote the inverse of a function $f$ is not borrowed from computer science and is a fairly old tradition, certainly predating electronic calculators. As for blackboard bold, it is familiar and very useful for those of us who were brought up on it or who have grown accustomed to it as it leaves regular bold $\mathbf{N}$, $\mathbf{Z}$ etc. free for other purposes.

Comment: @RobArthan: For a general function, I know. What is more recent is $\sin^{-1}$ for $\arcsin$ or $\sinh^{-1}$ for $\operatorname{argsinh}$ or even $\operatorname{argsh}$, which was in use when I was a student.

Comment: Mathematics is supposed to be referentially transparent: which means that if $f^{-1}$ makes sense for an indeterminate $f$, then it should also make sense for a specific $f$ like $\sin$. Actually, mathematical notation is far from referentially transparent, so we just have to live with ambiguities that have to be resolved by taking into account the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the basic formula is that $\;\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is the derivative of $\arcsin x$ (or of $-\arccos x$). By the substitution $x=at$, you obtain the standard formula
$$\int \frac1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx =  \arcsin \frac{x}{a},$$
and you obtain, with the initial condition $y(0)=2$,
$$y(x)=2+\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{a^2 - t^2}}\,\mathrm dt=2+ \arcsin \frac{x}{a}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It should be:
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}}{dx} = {\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}}} + C$$
Check again the integral table.
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2 - x^2}}$$
$$y=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2 - x^2}} dx=\arcsin{\frac{x}{2}} + C$$
$$y(0)=2 \implies C=2 $$

Comment: It's arcsin not sin.

Comment: oops sorry yes corrected. @AnginaSeng